# videoView progressbar shows a wrong time

Tags: android

The problem is that my video has 8 minutes and the progressbar just shows 1,20 minutes!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

VideoView v;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
  String url = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/" + R.raw.gozosos;
  v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
  v.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
  v.start();
  v.requestFocus();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem converting the video to the 3gp format.